# How to group the different row data with same type id in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

The table is like this

```
blog
----
id
type
lang
title
content
```

so example data is

```
id  type lang title content
1    1    1    abc    edf
2    1    2    abcxz    edf
3    2    1    asdc    df
4    2    2    ggf    edsdff
5    2    3    ssdf    sdf
```

The lang is the blog language e.g. 1 for english and 2 for French, 3 for Germany

So instead of show all row, I would like to group by type

e.g.

The result should be 2 row only

```
for type 1
title_en, title_fr, ..

and for type 2
title_en, title_fr, title_de ..
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` should help:

```
SELECT lang,
       Group_concat(Concat(lang, ':', title))
FROM   blog_titles
GROUP  BY lang
```